# Return the maximum value of rows in a 2d array

Tags: java

I am currently working on a method that calculates the sum of each row in a 2D array. However I am having trouble with one particular aspect in that I want to calculate the sum of the absolute values of each row and then return the maximum out of the 4 rows. So for example in my code below the maximum value would be rowTotalTwo which has the sum of 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pure and basic java...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] num = {// 0  1  2  3
            {4, 6, 9, 3},
            {6, 2, 4, 1},
            {8, 3, 7, 9}
    };
    int[] total = new int[num[0].length];

    for (int i=0; i < total.length;i++){
        total[i] = 0;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0 ; j < total.length; j++) {
            total[j] += num[i][j];
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i < total.length;i++){
        total[i] = Math.abs(total[i]);
    }

    int max = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < num.length;i++){
        if (max < total[i])
            max = total[i];
    }
    System.out.println("max : " + max);
}
```

using Collection

```
int max = (int)Collections.max(Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(total)));
```

using stream

```
int max = Arrays.stream(total).max().getAsInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, in which case you do not have to alter your code at all

```
Math.max(Math.max(Math.abs(rowTotalZero), Math.abs(rowTotalOne)), Math.max(Math.abs(rowTotalTwo), Math.abs(rowTotalThree)));
```